# Hidden div fading in when it's not supposed to

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function for a login script. If the result does not equal "success", it's supposed to fade in a div with the ID of status. The div starts fading in no matter what. Although, it logs in and redirects, you still see the div start fading in.

JS: *FYI, _ is a variable for `document.getElementById`*

```
function login() {
    var u = _("user").value;
    var p = _("pass").value;
    var status = _("status");

        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "login_script.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajax.responseText !== "success"){
                status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                if(_('status').style.display != "block"){
                        fadeIn('status');
                    };
            }
            else{
                window.location.href = "index.php";
            }
        };
        ajax.send(
            "u=" + u
            + "&p=" + p);
}
```

HTML:

```
  <form onsubmit="return false;" id="valid" class="mainForm">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="loginRow">
                    <label for="req1">Username:</label>
                    <div class="loginInput"><input type="text" name="user" id="user" /></div>
                </div>

                <div class="loginRow">
                    <label for="req2">Password:</label>
                    <div class="loginInput"><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /></div>
                </div>
                <div id="status" style="width:94%;"></div>
                <div class="loginRow">
                    <div class="submitForm">
                        <button id="loginbtn" onclick="login();" class="greyishBtn"> Login </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="forgot" style="padding:5px 15px;; float:right;">
                        <a href="forgot.php">Forgot/Reset Password</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

login-script.php

```
$username = $_POST['u'];
$password = $_POST['p'];

$query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT username, password, id_user, permissions FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");

$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$perm = $row['permissions'];



if($count==1){
    $seconds = 3600 + time();
    setcookie(loggedin, date("F js - g:i a"), $seconds);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id_user'];
    echo "success";
    }
    else{
        echo '<span style="color:red;">Please check your username and password and try again.</span>';
}
```

ajaxObj:

```
function ajaxObj(meth, url) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(meth, url, true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
        return true;
    }
}
```

If anyone wants to test it out: http://lucienconsulting.com/brick-academy/

username: jvincilione3@aol.com
password: password

You can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: post the contents of login_script.php

Comment: Ok. It's returning success tho, or it wouldn't redirect my page.

Comment: Post your ajaxObj function too.

Comment: The ajax is working, and it's returning the correct info and logging me in. The problem is that it's doing the fadeIn even though it's returning success. I'm posting the ajaxObj anyway, but that probably wont help anything.

Comment: Hmm, beats me. Try removing the semicolon after your if(display != 'block') statement.

Comment: Good idea. But unfortunately it still did it :( Thanks for your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34656/discussion-between-jack-and-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding another = sign for the second **If** like this:

```
if(_('status').style.display !== "block"){
                    fadeIn('status');
                };
```

If that doesn't work, you could try this:

```
if(status.style.display !== "block"){
                        fadeIn('status');
                    };
```

Comment: The problem is not in that if statement, that if statement should be skipped entirely.

Answer (score 0):

`onreadystatechange` may fire more than once.  You'll want to check that it's complete.

```js
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (ajax.readyState == 4) {   // complete
        if(ajax.responseText !== "success"){
            status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            if(_('status').style.display != "block"){
                    fadeIn('status');
                };
        }
        else{
            window.location.href = "index.php";
        }
  }
};
```

Comment: We don't necessarily know the implementation details of ajaxObj. It may not have that property; it's not an XMLHttpRequest, anyway.

Comment: Even if it fired 10,000 times, the first time it fires, it should redirect the page.

Comment: The first time it fires, you don't know if your request succeeded yet. We'll potentially fire on open, send, headers received, etc.